# multiple string replace function not working in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-mysql

Here I need to replace `#tenant_id#` in multiple files the input is coming from an `json` object as 1.

This is the first file to replace `#tenant_id#`:

```
INSERT INTO mst_designation (designation_name,tenant_id)
SELECT designation_name,#tenant_id# tenant_id FROM mst_designation  mdes
WHERE tenant_id = -1 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mst_designation 
WHERE designation_name = mdes.designation_name AND tenant_id = #tenant_id#);
```

Here **first `#tenant_id#` is replaced into `1` and second one is not replacing**

The code for replacing string :

```
  const dirPath = path.join(__dirname + '/script/')

  filenames = fs.readdirSync(dirPath)

  filenames.forEach(files => {
            file = fs.readFileSync(dirPath + files, { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' })

            fileReplace = file.replace("#tenant_id#", new_tenant_id)
            logger.log('silly', 'tenantOnBoard : tenant_id replace : Start ' + fileReplace);

             const queryCreateTenant = conPool.query(fileReplace)
             console.log(queryCreateTenant);
}
```

This is the code for replacing the string and here op is coming as

```
INSERT INTO mst_designation (designation_nametenant_id)
SELECT designation_name,#tenant_id# tenant_idFROM mst_designation  mdes
WHERE tenant_id = -1 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mst_designation 
WHERE designation_name = mdes.designation_name AND tenant_id = #tenant_id#);
```

**the #tenant_id# is not replacing on 2nd place**
How to resolve this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior in javascript. To replace a string multiple times you may use RegExp with `g` flag:

```js
fileReplace = file.replace(/#tenant_id#/g, new_tenant_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `replaceAll()`.

```js
var query = "INSERT INTO mst_designation (designation_name,tenant_id) "+
"SELECT designation_name,#tenant_id# tenant_id FROM mst_designation  mdes "+
"WHERE tenant_id = -1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mst_designation WHERE designation_name = "+ " mdes.designation_name AND tenant_id = #tenant_id#);"

var fileReplace = query.replaceAll("#tenant_id#", "new_replaced_id")

console.log(fileReplace)
```

The name is self-explanatory. Using `replaceAll()` you will replace all instances that match insetad of only the first one.